# Python: Combine multiple zipped files and output to multiple csv files

Tags: python-3.x, csv, awk, grep, gzip

**Edit 2:**
Adding in a few sample lines for reference. The first line is the column names.

```
field 1|field 2|field3|id
123|xxx|aaa|118
123|xxx|aaa|56
124|xxx|aaa|184
124|yyy|aaa|156
```

**Edit:**

- Open to non-Python solutions (grep/awk etc are ok)
- The csv files are pipe-delimited "|"
- I need to retain the headers

I have 20 .gz files (each ~100MB, zipped). Within each .gz file is a csv file, with many columns, including an index column 'id'. There are around 250 unique ids across all the files.

I need to output all the rows for each unique id to each csv (i.e. there should be 250 csv files generated).

How should I best do this?

I am currently using Python but it takes around 1 minute to generate each csv, I would like to know if there is any faster solution please.

```
output_folder = 'indiv_ids/'

# get list of files
list_of_files = [filename for filename in os.listdir() if filename.endswith(".gz")]

# get list of unique ids
for i in range(len(list_of_files)):
    df = pd.read_csv(list_of_files[i], sep='|', usecols=['id'], dtype=str, engine='c')
    id_list = df['id'].unique()

    if len(id_list) == 250:
        break

# load into a list for each id
list_df = {id:[] for id in id_list}

for filename in list_of_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='|', dtype=str, engine='c')

    for id in id_list:
        df_id = df[df['id'] == id]
        list_df[id].append(df_id)

for id in id_list:
    # join into one big df
    df_full = pd.concat(list_df[id], axis=0)
    df_full.to_csv(f'{output_folder}{id}.csv', sep="|", index=False)
```

Comment: hi, sorry for late reply - it works apart from the fact that the header is lost. appreciate if there is any idea how can I keep the header in each file please? if there is no solution I will accept yours as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Now that I have seen how your data looks, I think you want this:

```
gunzip -c *gz | awk -F'|' '$4=="id"{hdr=$0;next} hdr{f=$4; print hdr > f ".csv"; hdr=""} {print > f ".csv"}'
```

**Original Answer**

I presume your asking for *"any faster solution"* permits non-Python solutions, so I would suggest `awk`.

I generated 4 files of 1000 lines of dummy data like this:

```
for ((i=0;i<4;i++)) ; do
    perl -E 'for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++){say "Line $i,field2,field3,",int rand 250}' | gzip > $i.gz
done
```

Here are the first few lines of one of the files. The fourth field varies between 0..250 and is supposed to be like your `id` field.

```
Line 0,field2,field3,81
Line 1,field2,field3,118
Line 2,field2,field3,56
Line 3,field2,field3,184
Line 4,field2,field3,156
Line 5,field2,field3,87
Line 6,field2,field3,118
Line 7,field2,field3,59
Line 8,field2,field3,119
Line 9,field2,field3,183
Line 10,field2,field3,90
```

Then you can process like this:

```
gunzip -c *gz | awk -F, '{ id=$4; print > id ".csv" }'
```

That says... *"Unzip all the `.gz` files without deleting them and pass the results to `awk`. Within `awk` the field separator is the comma. The `id` should be picked up from the 4th field of each line. Each line should be printed to an output file whose name is `id` followed by `.csv`"*.

You should get 250 CSV files... pretty quickly.

**Note**: If you run out of open file descriptors, you may need to raise the limit. Try running the following commands:

```
help ulimit
ulimit -n 500
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `BEGIN{FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"}` (https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html)

Comment: also you are losing the csv-header so maybe change to something like  `gunzip -c *gz | awk -F, 'BEGIN{FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"} {if ($4 == "id") {h = $0;} else {id=$4; if  (hh[id]  != 1) print h > id ".csv";  print > id ".csv"} }'`

Comment: it returns an error: 

awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 { id=$4; print > id >>>  ".csv" <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1

Comment: `gunzip -c *gz | awk -F'|' '{ id=$4; print > id }'` works without ".csv" but it stops and throws an error after about 10 ids are done: awk: <my_id> makes too many open files

Comment: `gunzip -c *gz | awk -F'|' '{ id=$4; print>> id; close(id) }'` works! been running for past 5 minutes. now to figure out how to get the header in... Lutz's code throws an error at hh[id]

Comment: Maybe you could show the first 3-4 lines of two of your CSVs so folks can help?

Comment: I have updated my answer now that I have seen your input data. Please have another look.